# Powerpoint theme is displaying two charts when I export

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

When I save my Powerpoint theme as png, I'm getting two charts one inside the other.

[image]

I'm using Powerpoint 2013. How can I fix this?

Comment: Err... You're on StackOverflow... Are you sure your question is about programming/integrating Powerpoint or just about using it?

Answer (score 0):

I had to go normal view and delete other before saving.